# Dollar($) sign not working in Email template

Tags: php, email, html-email, email-client

I have built a custom email template. And assigned some variables with `{#paid_amount}` and so on.

All the variables get replaced but `paid_amount` not as expected. I have replaced something like this:

```
// Text file with HTML markups
$template = file_get_contents($template_url);

$paid_amount = '$1.00';
$pattern = array( 
              '/\{\#user_name\}/i', 
              '/\{\#paid_amount\}/i', 
              '/\{\#duration\}/i'  );
$replacement = array( 
              $user_name, 
              $paid_amount, 
              $duration );

$new_template = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $template);
```

Its print the amount `.00` in the email, and if i remove the sign `$` from the amount it print the `1.00`. I tested it in Gmail. Has anyone faced this before?

Even i tried with `&dollar;` but not working. Can anyone please tell me what i have missed or why it is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign:

```
$paid_amount = '\$1.00';
```

This is because `preg_replace()` is using the `$` in the *replace* parameter to address the contents of a capturing group.

Example:

```
$string = ">> hello <<";
$pattern = "/>> ([^ ]*) <</";

echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $string);
```

In the above example, `$1` addresses the contents of the first capturing group: `([^ ]*)` -> "hello".

Comment: Its hard to explain with (my) words, but easy by example.. :)